# XCode Simulator black screen

Tags: swift, uikit

I Just start learning UIKit, i got a problem when trying to run the program, my simulator is going well, but simulator only shows black screen, without any problem on terminal, is there someone recognize my fault?

here is my PageViewController and screenshot blackscreen

[image]

import UIKit

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIPageViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControllView: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var onboardingPage: [OnboardingModel] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        onboardingPage = [
            OnboardingModel(description: "Welcome to Future Box", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "treasure")),
            OnboardingModel(description: "Future Box will save your thoughts about about something and save it on your local data, you can set time for that", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Idea")),
            OnboardingModel(description: "And when you set the time for your thoughts, Future Box will remind you again when the time is up", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "clock"))
        ]
    }
}

extension OnboardingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return onboardingPage.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OnboardingCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingCollectionViewCell
        cell.setupPage(page: onboardingPage[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: How do you set the view controller to be displayed? Or do you set it at all?

Comment: I believe the OS appearance is set to dark and so the view color is black by default. So try changing the view color by adding this code ->  self.view.backgroundColor = .red. If this works, then you are good to proceed with the app development.

Comment: okay I found that my code is running well, with no error, and change the background color as you told me before, but my Collection View is doesn't show up, what should I do? @Saurabh

Comment: Do you set Project -> Main Interface to be your OnboardingViewController or Onboarding storyboard? Do you set the entry point arrow in the storyboard to point OnboardingViewController? Do you set collection view dataSource and delegate? Do you want OnboardingViewController to inherit PageViewController or UIViewController?

Comment: Well, did you set the collectionView delegate and dataSource in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible reasons:

- You set wrong Project -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface
  [image]
- Main Storyboard Base Name is wrong
  [image]
- Entry Point in the storyboard is not set

[image]

- Not set:

  ```
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
  ```
- Usage of

  ```
    class OnboardingViewController: UIPageViewController {}
  ```

  instead of

  ```
    class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController {}
  ```

- You can check your view hierarchy from the [visual debugger](https://pasteboard.co/tQeV4dohTlVs.jpg) to see what is on device's screen.